# Setting registry key value from powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

When I try to set a registry key from a powershell script it overwrites another key :

For example :

```
$registryKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Qualys\QualysAgent\ScanOnDemand\Vulnerability"
$valuedata = '1'
$valuename = "Scanondemand"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryKey -Name $ValueName -Value $ValueData
```

This sets registry key right. Then I change the `valuename`:

```
$valuename = 'ScanOnstartup'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryKey -Name $ValueName -Value $ValueData
```

On now the `Scanonstartup` is correct but the `Scanondemand` key is gone. It kind of renames the name instead of creating a new key.

Comment: Shouldn't you ensure the registry exist first ? See this [link](https://scriptingetc.wordpress.com/2020/01/17/force-qualys-cloud-agent-in-demand-scanning/). It may be the Qualys agent that monitors registry changes ...

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking to replace your second add with:

**New-ItemProperty**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not specify the PowerShell **drive** in the registry path.

You can either use the long form:

```
Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Qualys\QualysAgent\ScanOnDemand\Vulnerability
```

or make use of the fact that for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` PowerShell already has a drive set up by name `HKLM:`

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Qualys\QualysAgent\ScanOnDemand\Vulnerability
```

Your code would then be

```
$registryKey = 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Qualys\QualysAgent\ScanOnDemand\Vulnerability'
# or: $registryKey = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Qualys\QualysAgent\ScanOnDemand\Vulnerability'

$valuedata = '1'
$valuename = 'ScanOnDemand', 'ScanOnStartup'
# if the key does not already exist, create it first
if (!(Test-Path -Path $registryKey)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $registryKey
}
Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryKey -Name $ValueName[0] -Value $ValueData
Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryKey -Name $ValueName[1] -Value $ValueData
```

By using switch `-Force` to the `New-Item` cmdlet, you do not have to check if that key already exists because it will return either the existing key as object or the newly created one.  Because we have no further use for that object as such, we ignore it with `$null = New-Item ..`

After running this (as Administrator), you have created this keys structure in the registry:

[image]

And in subkey `Vulnerability` you now have these two entries:

[image]